# What is the multplicative identity of Formal Series Ring is a ring with unity and when does inverse exists

Tags: complex-analysis

Here $\mathbb{C} [[T]]$ refers to the Formal Series Ring over $\mathbb{C}$ given [image: here]

I want to show that this is a ring with multiplicative identity.

For convenience, let us refer to $\sum a_n T^n $by $(a_n)$

Hence, $(a_n) (b_n) = (\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k})$

Would it be correct to say that $(1, 0, 0, \dots )$ is the **multiplicative identity** of this ring?

I also want to determine when inverse of $(a_n)$ will exist

For this, we define $ord( (a_n) ) = $ largest $k\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} \ni$ $T^k | (a_n)$

Then, clearly $ord( \;(a_n) (b_n) \;) = ord( \;(a_n) \;) + ord(\;(b_n)\;)$

First of all, let $a_0\neq 0$, that is, $ord( (a_n) ) = 0$, then,

$( \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}) = (1, 0, 0 \ldots)$ can be recursively solved for $(b_n)$ with $b_0\neq 0$ or $ord((b_n)) = 0 $

Hence, $(a_n)$ is invertible when $a_0 \neq 0$ or $ord((a_n)) = 0$

Now, suppose $(a_n)$ is invertible with its inverse being $(b_n)$ but then we must have $a_0 b_0 = 1 \rightarrow a_0 \neq 0 \rightarrow ord((a_n)) = 0$

Hence, $(a_n) $ is invertible if and only if its order is $0$.

Is this correct?